# Guidelines for creating multiple icons in Android

Tags: android, icons, privacy

I am creating an app which will have two main modules and for this I am creating two launcher icons. This helps in launching the two modules separately for easy access. I would like to know if this required users consent or are there any privacy issues or guidelines that needs to be followed for this. Does this come under spamming the user. Will it be ok If tell the user on a prompt that an icon will be created for easy access of feature.

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you stick with single launcher icon?and inside the app you can let the users have the options to decide which module they wanna run???Isn't it better that way???

Comment: Yes that is possible and is a neat way. But unlike iOS, since android have this multiple launch icon concept, I thought why not try that.